# How to add a back button to the fragment in the action bar of an opened activity?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, navigationview

I have a `HomeActivity` that implements `NavigationView` **without ToolBar** (with ActionBar). In this activity I implement the `onNavigationItemSelected` that I use to navigate to `SettingsFragment`:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);

        ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        // more code
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new DashboardActivity()).commit();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                // more code
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,new SettingsFragment()).commit();
    }
```

In the `SettingsFragment` fragment I have a listener to open a new activity:

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_settings, container, false);
        FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.myfab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubSettingsActivity.class);
                fragmentView.getContext().startActivity(intent);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        return fragmentView;
    }
```

It opens an activity but without a back button to the previous fragment. What's the proper way to add this button in the action bar?

**EDIT**: I would like the button to go back to the previous fragment `SettingsFragment` and not to the activity that holds the fragments. Why implementing `NavigationView` is so hard?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your SubSettingsActivity's theme should extend
**Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar**
Then in java do in onCreate

```
        if (actionBar != null) {
            actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
            actionBar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
        }
```

Then in AndroidManifest where u declare SubSettingsActivity do:

`android:parentActivity="YOUR_ACTIVITY"`

YOUR_ACTIVITY is the activity that holds fragment

**Edit:**
If you wanna navigate back to the SettingFragment its better you use Android Jetpack navigation component.
It let's you seemlessly use fragments.
Here is the link:
https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-migrate

**How to implement Navigation Component** *:the simple way*

**Step 1:**
Add the required dependencies

```
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment:2.3.0-alpha05'
implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui:2.3.0-alpha05'
```

**Step 2:**
Goto res folder on Android Studio, right click it, new > android Resource File
Youll see the following dialog:
[image: See Screenshot]

**Note the Resource type, you must pick Navigation**

**Step 3:** Since your fragments have been created, goto the activity xml that holds your fragment e.g activity_main.xml add the following:

```
<fragment
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/adView"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/main_nav"
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_frag"/>
```

**NavHostFragment** is the class that will handle your fragments, **navGraph** will be your navigation file you created earlier.

**Step 4:** add your fragments to the navigation file, open your navigation file u created in step 2, switch the tab to design. As seen in the image below
[image]

**Note** yours will be empty. Use the add sign(1 in the screenshot) to add your fragments to the design view. Notice the (2 in the screenshot) start fragment, this the fragment that will be inflated first. Means when u open MainActivity, its the start fragment in the navigation graph that will be visible.

The curly arrows are the actions or navigations. For example, in my screenshot, start fragment goes to signup fragment and login fragment, it simply means where start fragment can navigate to within the fragments inside the graph. if its not defined in the navigation graph, it wont navigate. Other words, hey nav i will want to navigate from splash fragment to signup fragment or login fragment in the future, take note!

**Step 5:** when you want to navigate to a fragment from a fragment within the graph instantiate an instance of NavController:

```
     private NavController controller;

     @Override
     public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle 
     savedInstanceState) {
       super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        controller = Navigation.findNavController(view);
    }
```

**NavController** will let you navigate and i usually instantiate it onViewCreated()

then:

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
  @Override
   public void onClick(View view){
      controller.navigate(R.id.action_startFragment_to_anotherFragment);
   }
 });
```

To set your actionbar with the fragments, put the following code in onCreate() of host activity:

```
      NavController mNavigationController = Navigation.findNavController(this,R.id.nav_host_frag);
      NavigationUI.setupActionBarWithNavController(this, mNavigationController);
```

Also in host activity:

```
@Override
public boolean onSupportNavigateUp() {
    return mNavigationController.navigateUp();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

[Check this video for more](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IEO2X5OU3MY)

Comment: But how to make it go the the fragment `SettingsFragment` insead of the `HomeActivity`?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions but I just migrated to this way so I prefer to stick with it.

Comment: Once you see how simple it is, you'll love it

Comment: As there are no other answer to this issue, can you please expand your answer about Android Jetpack navigation component? Is it available for API 16? How should I add it to my code? I read the docs and the example there looks different from what I need.

Comment: @vesii can u mark as correct answer if it helps you