# Android: how to create a custom back button for fragments in a KIOSK app

Tags: android, fragment, fragment-backstack

I **CANT** use ActionToolbar because this is a KIOSK app with a custom header fragment that needs to be displayed at all time. Hence my situation, I have a basic ImageButton on the said header fragment, and I want to implement the functionality of a basic ActionToolbar.

I add my fragment to the main container like this:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.main_container, UserListFragment.newInstance())
                    .addToBackStack("foo")
                    .commit();
```

The question is, how do I restore the state of my `main_container` before the current fragment was replaced with `UserListFragment`.

Like : fragment A is showing, replacing fragment A with B, pressing some button in my header fragment to pop the fragment B so again fragment A is showing.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider switching to **Android Jetpack Navigation Component** it was created for your type of situation. 
Check:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/62252603/8714139

Cheers!

Comment: thanks, I already tried this out but my application is way too big to refactor it to using Nav Components.